# Why is my NSMutableSet empty?

Tags: ios

I have an object that has just one member with a property of type NSMutableSet called URLs. I have a view controller that is performing this loop:

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.links[%d].toString()", i];
NSString *links = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: link];
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:links];
NSString *lastPath = [URL lastPathComponent];

if ( [lastPath hasPrefix:comparisonString] ) {

[model.URLs addObject:links];

}

NSLog(@"Count: %d", [model.URLs count]);
```

But the log function prints 0 for me, and I'm positive I have a few cases where the if statement is true because I log that as well and see it fire a few times. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that model.URLs points to a valid NSMutableSet? If it's nil, you'll still get 0 for the count in the log statement, and the -addObject: call will just do nothing.

Comment: Hm. The model here, is just a subclass of NSObject with just one member, NSMutableSet *URLs, and a property on it with nonatomic and retain attributes. I have a similar model with just two strings in it and it works fine, do I have to manually call some alloc/init function on the NSMutableSet in the model's alloc/init code that an NSString might not need?

Comment: Any property has to be properly initialized. If you're assigning a string to your string property before you try to access that property, that's the initialization that you need. Likewise, you have to set your URLs property to point to a mutable set before you can use that set; otherwise, the property is just a nil pointer. It's easy enough to check -- just place a breakpoint on your NSLog statement and take a look at the URLs property.

Comment: Thanks, looks like my design's byproduct set those NSStrings before accessing them like you said, so I see what happened. As for my other files, I have xib files where the views and buttons come from, and now I realize they are being initialized in initWithNib:...thanks!